# Plasma: alt+key not working

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, plasma-5

After upgrading Kubuntu to 19.04, my <kbd>Alt</kbd> key isn't working in combination with other keys (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>). I need to enter Settings -> Input Devices -> Keyboard and change any option. After pressing "Apply", the keyboard works fine again. I have to do this every time I reboot my notebook. With `xev` and `showkey` I can see that the keypress is being recognized, but I don't know what else can I see to find what's the problem.

**Edit**
The output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard` is

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="latam"
XKBVARIANT="deadtilde"
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

I guess I have to change it to something more similar to my actual keyboard and see what happens...

**Edit:** I created a new user, the alt issue is not present in that account. After switching back to my original account, the alt issue was not present either until the next reboot... I'm really lost

Comment: Please show us the output of the command `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: Ok, `/etc/default/keyboard` does not set any XKBOPTIONS, so no explanation there. A new clean user, as you mentioned in a comment on the answer, sounds as a good step to make progress.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: I created a new user, the alt issue is not present in that account. After switching back to my original account, the alt issue was not present either until the next reboot... I'm really lost

Comment: Try the command `cat ~/.config/kxkbrc | grep -i options`

Comment: And this: `ls -l ~/.config/kxkbrc`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: `ResetOldOptions=false`

Comment: -rw------- 1 kako kako 188 may 28 10:50 /home/kako/.config/kxkbrc

Comment: Ok. Possible user level XKB options should have been saved in that file. Apparently not. The other theory was that it was root owned, and hence not saving changed settings, but that seems not to be the case either. Unfortunately I'm lost too.

Comment: I think it's fixed: I've changed the task switcher and now seems that everything is working... a little strange to me

Comment: Great! Can't say I understand, but OTOH I don't use Kubuntu myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you can fix the problem during a session but it reappears after a reboot, please try to use the settings in the image below:

**System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Desktop Session**

[image: Desktop Session options]

(Also, if you've added a lot of widgets, or carried them over from before you upgraded to 19.04, please try inactivating them if necessary.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting with an empty session and I've cleaned all the widgets. I'm gonna see what happens with a new clean user

Comment: I created a new user, the alt issue is not present in that account. After switching back to my original account, the alt issue was not present either until the next reboot... I'm really lost

Comment: In other words, are things now working normally for you **only** with the new user?

Comment: not **only** for the new user, for both users, but only after I log in with the new user